# Indexing/Slicing of Collections in Scala

Tags: scala

I saw some really cool methods to operate on Scala Collections but I wanted to know how can one do the slicing operation in Scala? I see methods like `dropLeft` `take` but curious to know if something simpler like indexing or slice exists in Scala.

For example:

`val aString = "I want this word"`
`val aList = List(1,2,3,4)`

should return:

`val slicedString = aString.slice(7,11) => "this" //JavaScript type`

and

`val slicedList = aList.slice(0,2) => List(1,2) //JavaScript type`

or indexing like how it's done in python:

`val slicedString = aString(7:11) => "this"`

`val slicedList = aList(0:2) => List(1,2)`

Comment: `val slicedString = aString.slice(7,11)` does [slice](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#slice(from:Int,until:Int):List[A]) and return "this".

Comment: Hmm okay and does it slice list as well?

Comment: "Hmm okay and does it slice list as well?" – What happened when you opened up the documentation for List and scrolled down to 's'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you bothered to consult the [ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.7/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#slice(from:Int,until:Int):List%5BA%5D) you would have found what you're looking for.

```
aString.slice(7,11)  //res0: String = this
aList.slice(0,2)     //res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```